# Basic recursion on string?

Tags: python, string, recursion

I want to have a program that prints me a word in this way only by recursion and if-else clauses:

> P
>   Py
>   Pyt
>   Pyth
>   Pytho
>   Python

Why does following code not work? It gives me an error of maximum recursion depth exceeded.

```
def oneToAll (word, x):
    if -x < 0:
        print(word[:-x])
        oneToAll(word, x+1)
    else:
        return

wordOutside = "Python"
oneToAll(wordOutside, len(wordOutside))
```

Comment: Don't you want `x - 1` when you recurse instead of `x + 1`?

Comment: Recursing over strings is tricky, because you can iterate over an empty string...

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- OP isn't really iterating over the string though.  The recursion is actually passing an index down.  It's probably not a typical way to do the recursion in python, but I think it makes sense for this problem as op wants to print `'P'` _before_ `'Py'`, etc.

Comment: You have infinite recursion because the length of a non empty string will always be positive and because your recursive case always increases x, hence `-x` will always be less than 0

Comment: Why are you using `-x < 0` instead of simple `x > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def oneToAll (word, x):
    if -x < 0:
        print(word[:-x])
        oneToAll(word, x-1)
    elif x == 0:
        print(word)
    else:
        return

wordOutside = "Python"
oneToAll(wordOutside, len(wordOutside))
```

This seems to work.  Note that I've now recursed using `x-1` instead of `x+1` because you want `x` to always be working its way toward `0`.

Implementing this way, you have to handle the special case where `x == 0`.  In that case, you want to print the entire string, not `word[:0]` (which is always an empty string).  Also note that I didn't recurse further from the `0` branch.  This is because at this point, you're done.  You can actually remove the `else` clause entirely (give it a try!).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but you could achieve the same thing like this:

```
def one_to_all(w):
    if w:
        one_to_all(w[:-1])
        print w

one_to_all('Python')
```

Your code doesn't work because (i) you add 1 to x instead of subtracting 1 and (ii) when x reaches zero, `word[:-x]` is an empty string, so you need to deal with that case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with intuitive index of "word"

```
def oneToAll(word, x):
    if x > 1:
        print (word[0:len(word) - x])
        oneToAll(word, x - 1)
    elif x == 1:
        print (word)

wordOutside = "Python"
oneToAll(wordOutside, len(wordOutside))
```